# En una calculadora hecha en python, cómo puedo hacer un botón que al presionarlo me haga más grande la letra de todos los botones?

Tags: python, tkinter

Necesito que todas las letras aumenten, incluyendo la del mismo botón.
Y luego un botón que haga el proceso inverso: disminuir el tamaño de las fuentes.

Estoy usando Tkinter, y los objetos (botones), están dentro de un grid, de manera que se colocan con filas y columnas, y si al hacer más grande la letra, crece el boton, no hay problemas porque se ajusta a la celda.

tam, es el tamaño que quiero que se modifique en este boton, y en todos los botones cuando presiono el botonAumentar.

```py
botonAC = Button(ventana, font= ('Arial', ***tam, 'bold'), text= 'AC', bg='#FA8258', command= lambda : limpiarAC())
botonAC.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(E, W, N, S), pady=5, padx=5)
```

Comment: Bienvenida Natalia a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Por favor, agrega un [mcve] para poder ayudarte, ni siquiera sabemos que librería de GUI estas usando. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @Natalia, hay una solución proporcionada por @BryanOakley, a través de 2 funciones `bigger()` y `smaller()` en este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840070/change-font-size-without-messing-with-tkinter-button-size/42840418), la idea sería importar `tkFont` y configurar el tamaño a través de `font.configure`. Me hubiese gustado postear la respuesta completa en español -si alguien puede sería estupendo- pero actualmente no dispongo de **SO Windows** para ejecutar la biblioteca `tkinter` porque **macOS 10.6 o posterior** tiene serios *bugs*, que impiden ejecutar bien `tkinter`.

Answer (score 0):

Natalia, hice un ejemplo simplificado ignorando el hecho de que se trate de una calculadora, pero centrándome en el problema del tamaño de la fuente. El código no tiene mucha ciencia, lo más importante es que te centres en la línea:

> font.nametofont('TkDefaultFont').configure(size=tamano_fuente)

En donde **font.nametofont('TkDefaultFont')** captura la fuente usada por defecto, y luego se asigna el nuevo tamaño.

Los botones "+" y "-" están llamando a la función **cambiarTamano**, entregando como parámetro, la cantidad en la se incrementará (o decrementará) el tamaño.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, LEFT
import tkinter.font as font

def cambiarTamano(valor):
    global tamano_fuente
    tamano_fuente += valor
    font.nametofont('TkDefaultFont').configure(size=tamano_fuente)

v = Tk() 
v.title("Calculadora corta")
tamano_fuente = 14

boton_1 = Button(v, text="1")
boton_2 = Button(v, text="2")
boton_3 = Button(v, text="3")
boton_mas = Button(v, text="+", command=lambda: cambiarTamano(1))
boton_menos = Button(v, text="-", command=lambda: cambiarTamano(-1))

boton_1.pack(side=LEFT)
boton_2.pack(side=LEFT)
boton_3.pack(side=LEFT)
boton_mas.pack(side=LEFT)
boton_menos.pack(side=LEFT)

v.mainloop()
```